# Creating Polygon from groups of points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clustering, vector-layer, convex-hull

I have a point feature class (Address Points) and I am interested in creating a polygon feature class around groups of 500 address points. Is there a way I can do this programmatically, as opposed to manually creating grids?

Comment: have a look at question about convex or concave hull they probably will answer your question

Comment: Are you wanting to draw a polygon using points as vertices, such as a hull?  Or are you wanting to create a grid whose cells encompass 500 points each? Or simply group points based on proximity?  For clarification [this](https://community.esri.com/thread/195092-group-every-near-50-points-together?commentID=687372#comment-687293) post discusses grouping.

Comment: Apologies, I am using ArcGIS 10.6. Creating a grid with cells encompassing 500 points each would be ideal, but a hull might not be a bad idea either, as I could clean up the resulting polygons as needed.